# Is it possible to create a GridView that has children of different sizes?

Tags: android

So let's try to explain what I am trying to do...

I have a design that looks like this -

![alt text][1]

For this I have I created two GridViews like so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView style="@style/GroupName"
                  android:text="@string/currency_badges"/>

        <GridView android:id="@+id/currency_grid"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:columnWidth="90dp"
                  android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                  android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                  android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                  android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                  android:gravity="left"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView style="@style/GroupName"
                  android:text="@string/foursquare_badges"/>

        <GridView android:id="@+id/foursquare_grid"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:columnWidth="90dp"
                  android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                  android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                  android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                  android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                  android:gravity="left"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am not really happy with it because as you can see the top right icon's label is hidden. I can click and scroll but that's not what I want. Also the bigger problem is that each *`GridView` HAS ITS OWN SCROLLBAR*. Again not what I want. So I think I would like to use one `GridView` to accomplish this. How can I use a `GridView` to have icons and then show the GroupName in the middle of the icons. I know I can create a `BaseAdapter` to return different types of Views, but I need to have one item that takes horizontally the whole space. Is this possible?

**Edit:**

**I guess a better question is how do I create grouped GridViews?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are adding items right now, but you might look at using a [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html).  It lets you supply an xml layout and map items from your data objects into places in the xml layout.  There are a number of tutorials for using it if you do a quick search.

Comment: That's what I am doing right now. Except I am using a BaseAdapter. I know I can return different Views. My question is when I set width to fill_parent, it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question (Although SimpleAdapter is likely easier to use than BaseAdapter).  You are saying you want a widget that supports multiple sections, each with a GridView in it.  I don't think there is any such widget out of the box, you would need to create your own.  How many icons do you expect to show?  If you aren't that concerned with the object reuse GridView gives you you could probably easily accomplish what you want with a LinearLayout or TableLayout in a ScrollView.

Comment: After careful consideration, I think this is not possible. You are right and I need to create my own widget which is not worth my time right now.